# Error in query (7): ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \copy persons (supervisor_lname, supervisor_fname, lname, fn

Tags: postgresql, file, import

How to fix this error, when I try to copy a csv into my personal database table, it gives this error.
Bigger background is I want to import a csv file from local to my database to as an extract and dependent table. Don't know how to directly load the file to be a table, so, I first create an empty table, then copy the csv file to this empty table.

This is the command I used:

```
\copy persons (supervisor_lname, supervisor_fname, lname, fname, supervisor_id)
FROM '/Users/baoying/Downloads/sql.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Please show the offending line from the CSV file.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run this?  `\copy` can only be used in `psql` it's not a valid [SQL command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: -a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: -a_horse_with_no_name, I use on SQL.

Comment: what is the offending line please ?

Comment: cat /Users/baoying/Downloads/sql.csv | psql <database_name> -c "COPY persons (supervisor_lname, supervisor_fname, lname, fname, supervisor_id) FROM stdin DELIMITER ',' csv header"

Comment: Instead of cat, you can use pv (Which needs to be installed under Ubuntu) to have a fancy progress bar.